# Group by count NAs as zeros

Tags: r, dplyr

I try to count values in `group_by` with `NA` in one column of data frame. I have data like this:

```
> df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, NA, 4, NA),
                 group = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
> df
  id group
1  1     A
2  2     A
3  3     B
4 NA     C
5  4     D
6 NA     E
```

I want to count groups having `NA` in first column as 0, but with an approach like this

```
> df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(n = n())
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  group     n
* <chr> <int>
1 A         2
2 B         1
3 C         1
4 D         1
5 E         1
```

i have `1` in rows `C` and `E` but not `0` which i want.
The expected result looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  group     n
* <chr> <int>
1 A         2
2 B         1
3 C         0
4 D         1
5 E         0
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the `sum` of a logical vector created with `is.na` to get the count as `TRUE => 1` and `FALSE => 0` so the `sum` returns the count of non-NA elements

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(group) %>% 
   summarise(n = sum(!is.na(id)))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#    group     n
# * <chr> <int>
#1 A         2
#2 B         1
#3 C         0
#4 D         1
#5 E         0
```

---

Or use `length` after subsetting

```
df %>%
   group_by(group) %>% 
   summarise(n = length(id[!is.na(id)]))
```

---

`n()` returns the total number of rows including the missing values